# How to fix "missing configuration file: ['config.py']" when importing cv2 on replit

Tags: python, opencv, replit

I am trying to use python's opencv (or cv2) module for a project on replit. When I import the class cv2

```
    from cv2 import cv2
```

I get the following error (on my replit console)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
          from cv2 import cv2
       File "/home/runner/picture-filters/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
          bootstrap()
       File "/home/runner/picture-filters/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 111, in bootstrap
          load_first_config(['config.py'], True)
       File "/home/runner/picture-filters/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 109, in load_first_config
          raise ImportError('OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: {}. Check OpenCV installation.'.format(fnames))
    ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.
```

Can someone explain to me how I can fix this error?
I have looked online for solutions, but all I can find are windows specific and linux specific solutions that DO NOT work for replit.

Comment: sounds like you should contact repl.it for support

Comment: Reinstall again. Or get file from github.